# Grails GORM in Spring tool suite

Tags: grails, grails-orm

The following artical code works in 'grails console'. But when I try to run it in STS its giving compile error for the domain class.

http://timsporcic.github.io/GORM-Recipes/

Is it possible to run in STS, I want to test to GORM methods before using it in contolers. even console command from STS is not working.

trying to run like this:

```
class Test {

    static main(args) {
        new BootStrap().init()
println Person.get(1)
        }
}
```

thanks

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "in STS"? Do you mean you're running a class using its `main` method, or starting `run-app` through STS?

Comment: I am using class with main method. run-app works fine for me

Comment: What error you get running `grails console`?

Comment: @sergio-michels, the above code works fine in grials console, when I run the same class in STS, it giving the error message

Answer (score 0):

`Run as > Groovy Script` will not work. `grails console` works different, because you have you application fully initialized (same for `run-app` and `test-app`).

If you want to test your `BootStrap` class I suggest you to create one [integration test](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/testing.html#integrationTesting). This will also ensure that, if you change your class, the logic still works.